# requirejs optimizer window is not defined error

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, requirejs

I am making an app which is using node, backbone and requirejs together. I need to optimize the js but I am running into the error `Reference Error: Window is not defined` when I try to run the optimized file using node through command prompt.

I searched for solutions and read about [plugin-builder](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) and also found an [example](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/tests/plugins/index.js), but I am not sure exactly how to make that thing work.

I have my main file main.js in which I have defined config for `requirejs(paths,shim etc.)` and a build.js for optimizer in which I have defined the parameters for optimizing

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    mainConfigFile: 'main.js',
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

Any help on how to proceed further?

Comment: Do you have your full code repo online anywhere?

Comment: well I am fairly certain that `window` is something that is defined in the browser, not your node.js command line

Comment: You should do a quick search in your project files to "Windows", this is probably just a typo.

Comment: @jcreamer898 no, i dont have the code online.

Comment: @jakee yes, the node enviornment and browser enviornment are different, but since my code logic contains use of the window object and the code is being optimized and brought under one file, I am facing the issue

Comment: @akoskm This is not a typo